# Superposition dimension a la Kolmogorov/Arnold

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, manifolds, universal-algebra

*(Now [asked at MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/412407/analogue-of-kolmogorov-arnold-superposition-for-general-manifolds).)*

Given a topological space $\mathcal{X}$, let $$\mathsf{Cl_C}(\mathcal{X})=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}C(\mathcal{X}^n,\mathcal{X})$$ be the **clone of finite-arity continuous functions on $\mathcal{X}$** (where $\mathcal{X}^n$ is given the product topology). Motivated by the [Kolmogorov-Arnold superposition theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Arnold_representation_theorem), let the **superposition dimension** of $\mathcal{X}$ be the minimal cardinality of a set of continuous functions $\mathfrak{F}\subseteq\mathsf{Cl_C}(\mathcal{X})$ such that the clone generated by $\mathfrak{F}\cup C(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{X})$ is all of $\mathsf{Cl_C}(\mathcal{X})$.

Some quick observations:

- Any space homeomorphic to its square trivially has superposition dimension $1$: there is no real distinction between single- and multi-variable continuous functions over such a space once we bring in an appropriate pairing function.
- The K/A theorem says that the superposition dimension of $[0,1]$ is $1$, witnessed by $\{+\}$.

  - Admittedly the failure to distinguish between Cantor space and the unit interval suggests that the word "dimension" is being wildly misused, but meh.
- It is **not** clear to me that shifting attention to maps with codomain $[0,1]$ results in the same notion (I strongly suspect it doesn't), so e.g. [Ostrand's extension of the K/A theorem](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1965-71-04/S0002-9904-1965-11363-5/S0002-9904-1965-11363-5.pdf) doesn't seem relevant here.

I'm generally curious for any relevant information, but the following particular question seems interesting: is there, for each finite $n$, a "nice" topological space with superposition dimension $n$? Of course this is really a whole family of questions, one for each meaning of "nice."  Tentatively I think the most interesting case is likely to be the following:

> **Question**: Is there, for each finite $n$, a connected topological manifold *(with or without boundary, not necessarily compact)* with superposition dimension $n$?

I suspect that every topological manifold has superposition dimension $1$, by some not-too-complicated extension of K/A, but I don't immediately see how to show that.